# Composite wpf(Prism) using custom controls within modules

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am rewriting my project with a modular approach using the prism framework, but have a small issue that I cant find the solution to.

Initially I have a custom canvas control which I have written to allow me to drag its child elements to the desired positions on the screen.

```
    public class SpecialCanvas : Canvas
```

The canvas is part of a class library called MainDiagram Module, and the library contains a class which implements IModule.

```
    public class MainDiagramModule : IModule
{
    private readonly IRegionManager regionManager;

    public MainDiagramModule(IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.regionManager = regionManager;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        ResourceDictionary dictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
        dictionary.Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MainDiagramModule;Component/Resources.xaml");
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);

        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MainRegion", typeof(SpecialCanvas));
    }
}
```

My Shell.xaml class contains an ItemsControl to provide the region for the canvas to be added to.

```
<Window x:Class="MLinkPrismVersion.Shell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:Prism="http://www.codeplex.com/prism"
    Title="MachineLink" Height="700" Width="1000">
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl Name="MainDiagram" Height="500" Width="800" Prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MainRegion"/>
</Grid>
```

My problem is that whenever MeasureOverride() is called on my SpecialCanvas class, the Size passed as a parameter gets the width from the parent, in this case 800, but the height is always infinity.
Is there any way to sort this. 
The project was previously written in a non mvvm/prism way where I simply instantiated specialcanvas in the Mainwindow_Loaded event and added it into a grid in mainwindow.xaml, the measureoverride method was always passed both sizes of the parent.

Comment: Solved this one, changed ItemsControl in shell.xaml to a ContentControl.

Comment: Put that in the answer section. Then set it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this one, It would seem that by changing the ItemsControl in shell.xaml to a ContentControl, both height and width get passed to MeasureOverride().